# Add column to hive table using cascade keyword

Tags: hive

I have a hive table, I want to add column into it. 
Query is :

```
ALTER TABLE maineventslog ADD COLUMNS (test_column int) CASCADE;
```

I am getting below error :

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10006]: Partition not found.
```

Why column is not getting added. Hive version is Hive 1.1.0-cdh5.4.0

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to have CASCADE there. Following command should work :

ALTER TABLE maineventslog ADD COLUMNS (test_column int)

Comment: Because i want my metadata to be updated, I have resolved the issue, since my table contains plenty of partitions its taking time, with less number of partitions i am able to add column with 'cascade' .